# Copying formula and Format from row above Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet for entering a new set of data on a new row each day each day, the row contains formulas and formatting. I want to be able to click a button and it adds a row under the last row with entered data and copy the formulas and formatting only, ready for new data to be entered.

Below is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim varUserInput As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    With ws
         varUserInput = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Rows(varUserInput).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        .Rows(1).Copy .Rows(varUserInput)

        .Rows(varUserInput - 1).Copy
        .Rows(varUserInput + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The issue is that it will only copy the formula from the same hidden row each time.

Comment: Which row has the formatting?

Comment: any row above this new row, but row 3 at the moment

Comment: Try the code that I posted.. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes worked perfectly! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (UNTESTED)?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim varUserInput As Variant

    varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", "What Row?")

    If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change as applicable

    With ws
        .Rows(varUserInput).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        .Rows(1).Copy .Rows(varUserInput)

        .Rows(varUserInput - 1).Copy
        .Rows(varUserInput).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: that is perfect, worked just as I wanted! Thank you very much

Comment: would there be a way of adding a row below the last in the list rather than selecting the row number?

Comment: Yes. Please see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) to find the last row which has data. Simply add 1 to that row to get the new row

Comment: Brilliant, very helpful

Comment: Update your question with the code that you are trying now

Comment: I'm using exactly what you posted and nothing else

Comment: I haven't got it in, I cant make it work unfortunately. Instead of asking what row I want to add, i'd like it to automatically find it using that line but I can work out what to remove and what to add

Comment: I can give you the code but then you will not learn.. Please read the link that I gave you on how to find the last row...

Comment: thats fair enough, I shall update the question with the closest I have come